# Rails Server is not starting on Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using windows 10. I install Rails and other supporting software via railsinstaller.org website.

Now I go on CMD and writing command `rails server` but Rails server not starting work. when I open link in firefox http://localhost:3000

Following is snapshot of output when I write `rails s` in cmd. I have Rails 4.2.5.1 in my PC and using Windows 10

[image]

Comment: are you sure when you run `rails s` that you're inside the project folder?

Comment: yes I am inside the project folder......

Comment: provide the output of `dir` command of your project directory, it look like you are not in your project directory

Comment: Yes I was not in project directory but when I change directory. A new error occurred

Comment: New error is "Could not find gem 'uglifier (>=1.3.0) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem my be caused due to following (Unable to Install gems)**

if you are using latest version of ruby installer to install ruby then there are problem for installing  nokogiri and ulifier or other gem which needs to compailing in your pc. so you needs to install devkit first. For this please  do following:

The download is a self-extracting archive. When you execute the file, it’ll ask you for a destination for the files. Enter a path that has no spaces in it. We recommend something simple, like `C:\RubyDevKit\`. Click Extract and wait until the process is finished.
[Download from here](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)

Next, you need to initialize the DevKit and bind it to your Ruby installation. Open your favorite command line tool and navigate to the folder you extracted the DevKit into.

```
cd C:\RubyDevKit
```

Auto-detect Ruby installations and add them to a configuration file for the next step.

```
ruby dk.rb init
```

Install the DevKit, binding it to your Ruby installation.

```
ruby dk.rb install
```

Now run bundle install

If still problem persist downgrade your ruby or install linux distro.

Comment: this is not the solution for the problem. My devkit is setup but still rails server doesn´t start. Temporary running server running puma directly

Comment: You can share what is displayed in terminal or cmd then we can find problem. Answer is for how to install uglifier gem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your directory to the app root folder.For Example if your app name is 'myapp', then type `cd myapp` and run rails server with `rails s`.

Comment: I change directory now I am in `C:\Sites\myrubyblog` now I have different error.

Comment: New error is "Could not find gem 'uglifier (>=1.3.0) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.

Comment: @UmairIftikhar did you try to install the gem `gem install uglifier`? Or did you bundle install/update?

Comment: I did bundle install but that was also not working. How to install gem?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the bin/rails file is in place. If not, generate a new sample app, then copy the bin folder to it.

Answer (score 0):

simply add **gem "tzinfo-data"** to your Gemfile and run bundle install and you are good to go[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCzMa.png)

Comment: please don't include code snippets as images. Can you replace the image by the actual code?